# React render multiple components in a row

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a small chat app which has the following HTML structure.

```
<div className="my-message">
  <div className="mess">
    <p className="my-message">Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div className="mess">
    <p className="my-message">How are you</p>
  </div>
    <p className="time-i-sent">1m ago</p>
</div>

<div className="my-message other-message">
  <div className="mess">
    <p className="my-message other-message-2">Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div className="mess">
    <p className="my-message other-message-2">Great</p>
  </div>
    <p className="time-i-sent other-message-3">5m ago</p>
</div>
```

You can notice that messages in a row that are from the same user are just divs with `mess` class. If other user responds, a new `my-message` div wraps the messages that the user will send consecutively. I reflect them as React components.

Here is the `Messages` component equivalent to `my-message` div that wraps consecutive messages.

```
const Messages = (props: any) => {
  const isOtherUser = props.userId !== props.currentUser.id;
  return (
    <div
      className={`my-message ${isOtherUser ? "other-message" : ""}`}
    >
      {props.children}
      {props.lastMessage && (
        <p className={`time-i-sent ${isOtherUser ? "other-message-3" : ""}`}>
          {getTimeSince(props.time)}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is my `Message` component which should be wrapped by `Messages` component if they are from the same user consecutively.

```
const Message = (props: any) => (
  <div className="mess">
    {props.userId === props.currentUser.id ? (
      <p className="my-message">{props.text}</p>
    ) : (
      <p className="my-message other-message-2">{props.text}</p>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

And here is what I try to do

```
messages.map((message, index) => {
  if (index > 0 && messages[index - 1].userId === message.userId) {
     return (
       <Messages
         {...message}
         currentUser={currentUser}
         lastMessage={index === messages.length - 1}
       >
          <Message key={index} {...message} currentUser={currentUser} />
       </Messages>
    );
  } else {
    return (
       <Message key={index} {...message} currentUser={currentUser} />
    );
  }
})
```

It looks strange, but I want to check if the previous message was from the same user, just make a `Message` component and put it inside the current `Messages` component, if messages are from different users, make a new `Messages` component and add `Message` components inside it in case user sent multiple messages in a row so that in the end I have something like the following.

```
<Messages>
  <Message>Hi</Message>
  <Message>How are you</Message>
</Messages>
                                     <Messages>
                                       <Message>Hi</Message>
                                       <Message>Great, you?</Message>
                                     </Messages>
<Messages>
  <Message>Awesome</Message>
</Messages>
                                     <Messages>
                                       <Message>Bye</Message>
                                     </Messages>
```

I think this should be the logic but not sure how to achieve appending the components here I thought of HOC as well.

Comment: Why do you have Messages and Message as separate component?

Comment: Message have it's unique time right?

Comment: Can you explain more about, when you need to show the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to *reduce* the number of elements of `messages` grouping the ones with the same `userId`, you can try using `Array.reduce`:

```js
const groups = messages.reduce((acc, message, index) => {
  if (index > 0 && messages[index - 1].userId === message.userId) {
    // Same group as before
    acc[ acc.length-1 ].push({message, index});
  } else {
    // New group
    acc.push([{message, index}])
  }
}, []);

return groups.map( (group, groupIndex) => (
       <Messages
         key={groupIndex}
         {...group[group.length-1].message}
         currentUser={currentUser}
         lastMessage={groupIndex === group.length - 1}
       >
          { group.map( ({message, index}) => (
              <Message key={index} {...message} currentUser={currentUser} />
            ))
          }
       </Messages>
  )
);
```

But I think maybe it would be better to modify the `Messages` component, so it accepts an array of messages instead of using `children`.

Comment: I am trying to understand your solution. First, I think we should change in ```groups``` method, ```message``` with ```current``` parameter. I did not mention but I use TypeScript and I would like to ask that in ```groups``` we are going to return a message object for each from ```messages``` variable, am I right?

Comment: `First, I think we should change in groups method, message with current parameter` You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Here, `groups` is an array of arrays of messages, grouped by `userId` and maintaining original chronological order for each message.

Comment: Thank you it works as expected! I have one question, for the case when I send multiple messages, should I reuse this approach? As I understand this works for getting all messages that we already have. What about this being a realtime chat between 2 users, is it going to be the same?

Comment: `should I reuse this approach?` You only have an array of messages saved in the state/props. Whenever a new element is added to it (it will be a new array) the reduce should be re-executed. You can try some kind of optimization for long conversations, but it's outside of the scope of this question.